# Counting toxicity character variables across multiple columns in R and maintaining that information in the dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains toxicity data for medications. The rows are the observations (patients) and the columns contain a type of toxicity (these are multiple columns eg. tox1, tox2, tox3...), the time it occurred, and severity.

eg.

[image: 1]

focusing on say fatigue
rows 4 and 5, 6,9 had fatigue listed in Tox 1
rows 7,8,10 had fatigue listed in Tox 2

I think the best way to gather this tox data will be to create a column for each toxicity

So I want to create a Fatigue column with Yes and No Response
I have used this:

```
Dataset$Fatigue.any.grade <- ifelse(Dataset$Toxicity.1 == "Fatigue", "Yes","No")
```

which works fine for 1 column

but I can't do it for multiple columns,

```
Dataset$Fatigue.any.grade <- ifelse(Dataset$Toxicity.1|Dataset$Toxicity.2|Dataset$Toxicity.3|Dataset$Toxicity.4|Datase$Toxicity.4 == "Fatigue", "Yes","No")
```

Is there any way that I can create 1 toxicity column for fatigue incorporated from the 5 toxicity columns?

example of what  I aim to achieve:

[image: 2]

Comment: A tip here would be to use `across`. But I cannot provide an answer, because there is no minimum reproducible example, and it is clear how you want to combine the many variables into one.

Comment: Thanks Mossa, I edited my question to further clarrify want I wanted to achieve. See above

Comment: @r9ronaldor9 I've replaced my comments with an actual solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Where You Went Wrong

Unsurprisingly, your condition works as intended on a single column:

```
Dataset$Toxicity.1 == "Fatigue"
```

After all, you simply compare (using [`==`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Comparison.html)) the [`character`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/character.html) column `Dataset$Toxicity.1` to the `character` value `"Fatigue"`.  So the operation `Dataset$Toxicity.1 == "Fatigue"` will yield a [`logical`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/logical.html) column, with `TRUE` wherever `Dataset$Toxicity.1` contains `"Fatigue"` and `FALSE` wherever it does not.

However, in your attempt on multiple columns, you really **misinterpret the usage of [`|`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Logic.html)**.  The logical `|` operator works on `logical` columns (or more generally "[`vector`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/vector.html)s") of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s, and uses `OR` to compare their corresponding values:

```
c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) | c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

# [1] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
```

So if you were expecting your condition

```
Dataset$Toxicity.1 | Dataset$Toxicity.2 | Dataset$Toxicity.3 | Dataset$Toxicity.4 | Dataset$Toxicity.5 == "Fatigue"
```

to expand into something like this

```
(Dataset$Toxicity.1 == "Fatigue") | (Dataset$Toxicity.2 == "Fatigue") | (Dataset$Toxicity.3 == "Fatigue") | (Dataset$Toxicity.4 == "Fatigue") | (Dataset$Toxicity.5 == "Fatigue")
```

**you are sadly mistaken**.  By the order of operations, the clump of `|`s is evaluated first

```
# |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  (Dataset$Toxicity.1 | Dataset$Toxicity.2 | Dataset$Toxicity.3 | Dataset$Toxicity.4 | Dataset$Toxicity.5) == "Fatigue"
```

and that *result* is compared to the string `"Fatigue"`.

**The problem is that your `Dataset$Toxicity.*` columns are `character` rather than `logical`, so it makes no sense to compare them to each other using `|`.  Even if you *could*, the result would be a logical vector that could *not* be compared for equality (`==`) against the string `"Fatigue"`.**

## How to Fix It

If you want to do your implementation properly, you need to write out each `character` comparison, and then use `|` on the `logical` results:

```
Dataset$Fatigue.any.grade <- ifelse(
  Dataset$Toxicity.1 == "Fatigue" | Dataset$Toxicity.2 == "Fatigue" | Dataset$Toxicity.3 == "Fatigue" | Dataset$Toxicity.4 == "Fatigue" | Dataset$Toxicity.5 == "Fatigue",
  "Yes","No"
)
```

## How to Do Even Better

The [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) package offers [`mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) to create (or transform) columns, and [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) to manipulate multiple columns at once.

You can operate `across()` all your `Toxicity.*` columns with an improvised [formula](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-shortcuts) `~. == "Fatigue"`, which compares each (`.`) of those columns against the string `"Fatigue"`; and then you can use [`Reduce()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/funprog.html) to consolidate those (`logical`) results using `|`.

```
library(dplyr)

Dataset <- Dataset %>%
  mutate(
    # Create a new column: 'Fatigue.any.grade'.
    Fatigue.any.grade = across(
      # Look across all the columns whose names start with "Toxicity."...
        starts_with("Toxicity."),
        # ...and compare each column against the string "Fatigue".
        ~. == "Fatigue"
      ) %>%

        # Consolidate those logical results using OR (|), to show (TRUE) where ANY of
        # those columns contained "Fatigue".
        Reduce(f = `|`) %>%

        # Change the TRUEs and FALSEs into "Yes"s and "No"s.
        if_else("Yes", "No")
  )
```

## Note

I've written it with lots of comments, but you can easily shorten this `mutate()`:

```
mutate(
  Fatigue.any.grade = across(starts_with("Toxicity."), ~. == "Fatigue") %>% Reduce(f = `|`) %>% if_else("Yes", "No")
)
```

Naturally, you can do the same for diarrhea as for fatigue.  Just replicate the `mutate()` above, but with the column name `Diarrhoea.any.grade` and the formula `~. == "diarhhoea"`.

You can also make the comparison **case insensitive** by altering the formula like so: `~tolower(.) == "fatigue"`.  Thus, you can detect `"FATIGUE"` and `"fatigue"` and `"fATigUe"`, in addition to `"Fatigue"`.

---

## Update

By [request](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/123292597)

> ...say now I want to look at toxicity that was classifed as grade 2 or higher i.e Fatige grade 2 accross the columns. what would be the best way to code?

here is a more advanced solution that is conditional upon the grade (`tox*_Grade`):

```
# Define a grade range: 2 and higher.
min_grade <- 2
max_grade <- Inf


Dataset <- Dataset %>%
  mutate(
    Fatigue_Grade_n = (
      # Count fatigues...
      across(starts_with("Toxicity."), ~. == "Fatigue") &
      # ...whose grades are in a certain range.
      across(matches("tox\\d+_Grade"), ~ . >= min_grade & . <= max_grade)
      #                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      #                                CUSTOM FORMULA: Just use '.'
    ) %>%
      # Consolidate those logical results, to show (TRUE) where 'any()' of those columns
      # contained "Fatigue".
      apply(MARGIN = 1, FUN = any)

    # ...
  )
```

### Note

You can make the `tox*_Grade` [formula](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-shortcuts) arbitrarily complex to suit your needs.  Just remember the following:

- Precede the formula with the `~` symbol.
- Represent the `tox*_Grade` column as the `.` symbol.
- Treat the `.` column as the vector it is. So use *vectorized* operations (like `&` instead of `&&`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your explannation. I tried running the code and have gotten the following error. "x 5 arguments passed to '|' which requires 2", any suggestions?

Comment: @r9ronaldor9 Try it now!  I just fixed a minor error for **How to Do Even Better**, where I had (wrongly) used `do.call()` instead of the correct `Reduce()`.

Comment: amazing - works like a charm. Just another question say now I want to look at toxicity that was classifed as grade 2 or higher i.e Fatige grade 2 accross the columns. what would be the best way to code? 

really appreciate your help

Comment: @r9ronaldor9 For that, a reproducible dataset would really be helpful.  But my guess would be something like: `mutate(Fatigue_Grade_n = (across(starts_with("Toxicity."), ~. == "Fatigue") & across(matches("tox\\d+_Grade"), ~. >= n)) %>% apply(MARGIN = 1, FUN = any))`, where `n` is the minimum grade (like `2`) you wish to include.  This assumes that the `tox*_Grade` columns are identical in number and order to the `Toxicity.*` columns.

Comment: Note that you can customize the cutoff conditions in the improvised formula for `tox*_Grade`: like `~. >= 2` for grades of 2 or higher; and `~. > 2 & . <= 5`. for grades higher than 2 but no higher than 5.

Comment: thanks so much all working very nicely

Comment: @r9ronaldor9 Glad to hear it!  Would you kindly go to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69725501) and [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)?

Comment: Hi Greg, I am just trying to apply the formula to another database. is this part of the formlula ("tox\\d+_Grade") the column name for the grade?

Comment: @r9ronaldor9 Yes, the string `"tox\\d+_Grade"` is a regular expression, used by the [selection helper](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/select_helpers.html) [`dplyr::matches()`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html) to operate [`across()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) every column (like `tox1_Grade`, `tox2_Grade`, and so forth) that matches the pattern of `"tox"` followed by a number and then `"_Grade"`.

Comment: thanks Greg. trying to apply the code to other dataset i get the following error: Problem with `mutate()` column `dysphagia.radio.Grade_2plus`. 
i `dysphagia.radio.Grade_2plus = `%>%`(...)`.
x ‘&’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

the data is the same size. the column names is as follows: radiotherapy.toxicity.1 and 2 and for grade radiotherapy.toxicity.1.grade radiotherapy.toxicity.2.grade.

Comment: The code looks like this: my code looks like this: 
 dt <- %>% < mutate( dysphagia.radio.Grade_2plus = (across(starts_with("radiotherapy.toxicity."), ~. == "dysphagia") & across(matches("radiotherapy.toxicity.\\d+.grade"), ~. >= 2)) %>% apply(MARGIN = 1, FUN = any))

Comment: @r9ronaldor9 I'm not 100% sure this is the *only* problem, but your regex has an issue: it uses `.` where you expect a period (`"."`), but the `.` symbol is a [regex metacharacter](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearquest/9.0.1?topic=tags-meta-characters-in-regular-expressions) designed to match _literally anything_ (except a newline).  If you want to match periods, you'll need to escape the `.` like so: `"radiotherapy\\.toxicity\\."` and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

A `melt` and `dcast` should do what you want:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- setnames(cbind(data.table(obs = sample(10, 10)), as.data.table(t(replicate(10, sample(c("fatigue", "diarrhoea", "nausia", "rash", "ulcer"), 3))))), new = c("obs", "tox1", "tox2", "tox3"))
> dt
    obs      tox1      tox2      tox3
 1:   4   fatigue diarrhoea      rash
 2:   5   fatigue      rash     ulcer
 3:  10      rash     ulcer    nausia
 4:   9      rash    nausia     ulcer
 5:   8     ulcer    nausia diarrhoea
 6:   3     ulcer diarrhoea    nausia
 7:   6    nausia     ulcer   fatigue
 8:   2    nausia     ulcer   fatigue
 9:   7 diarrhoea   fatigue     ulcer
10:   1 diarrhoea      rash    nausia

> cbind(setorder(dt, obs), dcast(melt(dt, id.var = "obs"), obs ~ value, value.var = "variable")[, -1])
    obs      tox1      tox2      tox3 diarrhoea fatigue nausia rash ulcer
 1:   1 diarrhoea      rash    nausia      tox1    <NA>   tox3 tox2  <NA>
 2:   2    nausia     ulcer   fatigue      <NA>    tox3   tox1 <NA>  tox2
 3:   3     ulcer diarrhoea    nausia      tox2    <NA>   tox3 <NA>  tox1
 4:   4   fatigue diarrhoea      rash      tox2    tox1   <NA> tox3  <NA>
 5:   5   fatigue      rash     ulcer      <NA>    tox1   <NA> tox2  tox3
 6:   6    nausia     ulcer   fatigue      <NA>    tox3   tox1 <NA>  tox2
 7:   7 diarrhoea   fatigue     ulcer      tox1    tox2   <NA> <NA>  tox3
 8:   8     ulcer    nausia diarrhoea      tox3    <NA>   tox2 <NA>  tox1
 9:   9      rash    nausia     ulcer      <NA>    <NA>   tox2 tox1  tox3
10:  10      rash     ulcer    nausia      <NA>    <NA>   tox3 tox1  tox2
```

A value of `NA` indicates that the toxicity type was not found in that row. Otherwise, the value under `fatigue` etc. indicates which toxicity column it came from.

UPDATE: If you'd rather have just TRUE/FALSE under your toxicity type columns, it's an easy modification:

```
> cbind(setorder(dt, obs), dcast(melt(dt, id.var = "obs")[, present := TRUE], obs ~ value, value.var = "present")[, -1])
    obs      tox1      tox2      tox3 diarrhoea fatigue nausia rash ulcer
 1:   1 diarrhoea      rash    nausia      TRUE      NA   TRUE TRUE    NA
 2:   2    nausia     ulcer   fatigue        NA    TRUE   TRUE   NA  TRUE
 3:   3     ulcer diarrhoea    nausia      TRUE      NA   TRUE   NA  TRUE
 4:   4   fatigue diarrhoea      rash      TRUE    TRUE     NA TRUE    NA
 5:   5   fatigue      rash     ulcer        NA    TRUE     NA TRUE  TRUE
 6:   6    nausia     ulcer   fatigue        NA    TRUE   TRUE   NA  TRUE
 7:   7 diarrhoea   fatigue     ulcer      TRUE    TRUE     NA   NA  TRUE
 8:   8     ulcer    nausia diarrhoea      TRUE      NA   TRUE   NA  TRUE
 9:   9      rash    nausia     ulcer        NA      NA   TRUE TRUE  TRUE
10:  10      rash     ulcer    nausia        NA      NA   TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I'm sure this is a nifty way of achieving what you wanted to achieve, but I'm not sure how this answers OP's question...

Comment: @Greg Not sure what you're missing. As I said, if the OP substitutes "a", "b"... for the toxicity types, the `data.table` that results from the `dcast(melt(` has the "new" columns that are in the attached image of what the OP is trying to achieve. The new columns aren't appended to the end of the original table, but that's an easy fix.

Comment: I think OP wants to *calculate* whether or not each observation has at least one `"Fatigue"` among the `Toxicity.*` fields.  While your answer will achieve a `data.table` of roughly the same structure as OP's desired `data.frame`, I'm not sure how it logically calculates (as with `|`) the presence of `"Fatigue"`.

Comment: @Greg I updated my answer with the OPs toxicity terms and did a `cbind` with the original table. Can you see how it is essentially the same thing as the OP's image?

Comment: My bad!  I think I see what you're getting at, and how it extends elegantly to an arbitrary subset of toxicities.  Indeed this actually provides *more* information than OP sought!  If OP wants a `TRUE`/`FALSE` column, for whether or not (say) `fatigue` is present, all OP has to do is `mutate(fatigue = !is.na(fatigue))`.  **Good stuff!**

Comment: @Greg Thanks for taking another look. I added an update for the TRUE/FALSE option.

Comment: Nice touch, and you certainly have my upvote!  Just one issue though: when it come to the output from your supplemental solution in the **UPDATE**, your `NA`s should be `FALSE`s.